# Is it possible to change dropzone.js instance messages?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I am working currently on a project in which I'd like to provide hot language switch. I'd like to change dropzone.js instance messages **after it has been initialized**. That means that I already have dropzone(s) in my DOM and I'd like to retranslate them without refreshing the page or even destroying existing instances.

Current (although not very pretty) solution I am using is to call `dropzoneInstance.destroy()`, clear innerHtml of the element and re-instantiate the component.

What I'd like to do is to call something like `dropzoneInstance.setOption('dictDefaultMessage', 'lorem ipsum');` which will hopefully swap texts in current HTML. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is this:

`Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictDefaultMessage = "lorem ipsum";`

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but I am not looking for changing the default options. I'd like to retranslate dropzone.js instance that was already initialized in the DOM. That means changing the messages and forcing dropzone to re-render those messages in HTML w/o destroying existing instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are general options than you can change by default, you can use something like:

```
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictDefaultMessage = "New happy message";
```

This will change the message for all DropZones there are multiple message that you can find at the start of this list:

> to translate dropzone, you can provide these options:

http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-dictDefaultMessage

Here are all the option that you can change:

```
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictDefaultMessage = "Lore ipsum";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictFallbackMessage = "Lore ipsum";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictInvalidFileType = "Lore ipsum";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictFileTooBig = "Lore ipsum ({{filesize}}MB). Lore ipsum: {{maxFilesize}}MB.";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictResponseError = "Lore ipsum {{statusCode}}.";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictCancelUpload = "Cancelar";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictCancelUploadConfirmation = "¿Lore ipsum?";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictRemoveFile = "Lore ipsum";
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions.dictMaxFilesExceeded = "Lore ipsum {{maxFiles}} Lore ipsum";
```

Where the things inside brackets are the status message of those options

Comment: Yes, I am aware of such options. Please, take a look at my original question, especially on this part:  I'd like to change dropzone.js instance messages **after it has been initialized**. I am setting those options to initialize the message set. What I need is to tell dropzone afterward, that it should change those messages inside existing dropzone area.

Comment: Currently I haven't found any option to do it "on the fly" there's two options 1) do it how you're currently doing it (thing that you don't want) 2) As most of them are are message due to error, you can listen `error` event and change the respective data of that file, the other that are not because of error can be changed using their respective data, I'll try to leave an example for later, but that's the basic idea.

Comment: Ahh, that's the phrase I was looking for - "on the fly". Since I need all messages translated - including the initial "Drop files here" message - I'll have to stay with my current approach.

Comment: As of 2022 this no longer works unfortunately